# Search through a certain manpage-section in all man pages

Tags: manpage

I would like to search through subsection FILES in all man pages.

I have tried `man -K FILES:resolv.conf` and `man -K -S FILES  resolv.conf` in no way

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The -S option selects a section of the *manual*, the manual being the whole collection of man pages. The manual section can be 1 (Executables), 2 (System calls) etc. Not the section of a single man page as such. So for example

```
man -K -S 3 resolv.conf
```

will return the man page for res_init(3), a C library call that belongs into the section 3, Library calls, but not the man page for dig(1), which belongs to section 1 (executables).

Since this is a brute text search anyways, I would probably make an ad hoc search script using zcat and sed, or maybe a simple perl script.

EDIT: here is an example script, created as bash function.

```
function mfind { find /usr/share/man/ -iname '*.gz' -exec zcat {} \; | perl -ne '/.SH NAME/ and $n=<STDIN>;/.SH '$2'/ and $c=1;$c and /'$1'/ and $n and print "$n" and $n=""' ; }
```

Usage:

```
mfind expression mansection
```

for example

```
mfind utmp FILES
```

Bugs: does not consider /etc/manpath.config, uses /usr/share/man instead. No further options available.

Comment: According to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/gkyre.html) it is possible on Solaris. Is that not applicable to ubuntu?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not (and not to GNU man in general).

Comment: (There is no such thing as GNU man.  Neither the now-mostly-obsolete man package nor the man-db package which Ubuntu uses have ever been GNU projects.)

Comment: Yes, my bad; sorry.

Comment: Nice, but there is a simpler solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`man -K FILES`

Tested functional under ubuntu 12.04

Simple and effective.

[image: ManFiles1]

[image: ManFiles2]

[image: ManFiles3]

**In your specific case you are looking for:**

`man -K FILES "resolv.conf"`

[image: ManFiles4]

Answer (score 1):

Please file a bug for this, preferably against the man-db package in Debian, but you can file it in Ubuntu instead if you like.  I don't promise to get around to implementing it any time soon (I'm man-db upstream), but it's an interesting feature in Solaris that I was unaware of and it would have occasional uses.

Comment: I don't think it's so much a bug as an imperfectly assembled command.. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say no options. I've been trying to put together a consolidated file in  *.txt* or *.pdf* format of the complete man resource. The option I opted for was

```
man -a /bin/* > manList.txt
```

(still experimenting with it for improvement, obviously). I'm far from an expert, so it has its kinks(some groups of text have sections of characters not displayable, I assume something involving the encoding around the page-breaks, not sure.) However, in reference to your question, it seems feasible that

```
man -a 5 /bin/* /sbin/* > {your_output_file}
```

would be at least a workable option until you can find something better. I tested it, same encoding issue, but the data is there for access, just needs some TLC. Then you could search at your leisure with a txt editor. Hope this helps.

Comment: There's an easier way. See my answer.